# Send file to website with Indy TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy

I need the right way to send a file with `TIdTCPClient` to the `top4top` website.

I send it with the `WriteFile()` option in `TIdTCPClient` but it does not work, and send with a stream but I get a bad request.

```
var
  utf8: IIdTextEncoding;
  sid,result: string;
  lParam: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  sid := 'Z2jAmKM%2CA8Ik2dJxlR9NlZUW65b';
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    utf8 := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    lParam := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    lParam.AddFormField('sid', sid);
    lParam.AddFile('file_1_', OpenDialog1.FileName);
    lParam.AddFormField('submitr', '[ رفع الملفات ]');
    TCPC.host := 'up.top4top.net';
    TCPC.Port := 443;
    TCPC.ConnectTimeout := 100000;
    TCPC.ReadTimeout := 500000;
    TCPC.Connect;
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('POST /index.php HTTP/1.1');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Host: up.top4top.net');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----   WebKitFormBoundarySSk63dIh0HIAto8S');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('DNT: 1');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Origin: https://up.top4top.net');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Referer: https://up.top4top.net/');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1');
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36   OPR/57.0.3098.106');
    TCPC.Socket.Write(lParam);
    TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('');
    Result := TCPC.Socket.AllData(utf8);
    TCPC.Disconnect;
  end;
```

Comment: Using `TIdHttp.Post` would make this esier, especially the encryption (TLS).

Comment: thank you i can send it easy by idhttp or tnethttpcient but I want to learn about socket and how can use it to send file with idtcpclient

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to learn but this seems like a waste of time, all your problems can be solved in 5 minutes using the appropriate component, no need to reinvent the wheel at all. Indy comes with source code, if you want to learn, read the source and get up speed with all the various RFC's involving the challenge you are facing.

Comment: Thank you m.r There is no waste of time in science

Comment: @NewBinary If you really want to do this the hard way, I suggest you first send a working request with `TIdHTTP` and capture its output with a `TIdLog...` component, then replicate the same output using `TIdTCPClient`

Comment: try
      IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
        try
          lParam := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

          lParam.AddFile('file_1_', OpenDialog1.FileName);
          lParam.AddFormField('submitr', '[ رفع الملفات ]');
          IdHTTP1.IOHandler := LHandler;

          Src := IdHTTP1.post('https://up.top4top.net', lParam);
          Memo1.Text := Src;
        finally
          lParam.Free;
          LHandler.Free;
        end;
      finally
        IdHTTP1.Free;
      end;

Comment: this work fine but not with idtcpclient

Comment: Regarding the code you showed, it won't work as-is because you are making 3 mistakes: 1) your `boundary` attribute doesn't match what `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` actually uses. You need to use the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.RequestContentType` property to set the `Content-Type` header. 2) you are not sending a `Content-Length` header. 3) your call to `WriteLn('')` needs to be before `Write(lParam)`, not after. Also, do you have an `SSLIOHandler` assigned to activate SSL/TLS after connecting to the server before writing the HTTP request?

Comment: thank you I see if can resolve it by this way thank you

Comment: I change hier to boundary of idmultipart       TCPC.Socket.WriteLn
      ('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='+lParam.Boundary);   and I get  HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></htm

Comment: I get ok message   HTTP/1.1 200 OK   but the problem now in the time reading because I get this string in source code فضلاً انتظر جاري رفع الملفات .....

Comment: mean waiting downloading............

Comment: can some one test it Please

Comment: yes i  use IdLogDebug1 to test request  and i get wait downloading  text in pastebin       https://pastebin.com/raw/FhWfjuvu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several mistakes:

1. The value of the `boundary` attribute you are specifying in the `Content-Type` header does not match what `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` actually uses when encoding its MIME data. You need to use the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.RequestContentType` property to set the `Content-Type` header properly. Otherwise the server will not parse the data correctly.
2. you are not sending a `Content-Length` header at all. The server needs to be told how much data you are sending.
3. your call to `WriteLn('')` needs to be before the call to `Write(lParam)`, not after.  An HTTP message's headers and body are separated by a blank line.

Try this instead:

```
var
  sid, result: string;
  lParam: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  sid := 'Z2jAmKM%2CA8Ik2dJxlR9NlZUW65b';
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    lParam := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      lParam.AddFormField('sid', sid);
      lParam.AddFile('file_1_', OpenDialog1.FileName);
      lParam.AddFormField('submitr', '[ رفع الملفات ]', 'utf-8');

      TCPC.Host := 'up.top4top.net';
      TCPC.Port := 443;
      TCPC.ConnectTimeout := 100000;
      TCPC.ReadTimeout := 500000;

      // make sure you have an SSLIOHandler component
      // assigned to the TCPC.IOHandler property, and
      // its PassThrough property is set to False before
      // sending any data...
      TCPC.Connect;
      try
        // set PassThrough=False here if not already...

        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('POST /index.php HTTP/1.1');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Host: up.top4top.net');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Connection: close');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Content-Type: ' + lParam.RequestContentType);
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Content-Length: ' + IntToStr(lParam.Size));
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('DNT: 1');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Origin: https://up.top4top.net');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Referer: https://up.top4top.net/');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106');
        TCPC.Socket.WriteLn;
        TCPC.Socket.Write(lParam);

        Result := TCPC.Socket.AllData(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      finally
        TCPC.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      lParam.Free;
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: The problem in my code is hier TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Content-Type: ' + lParam.RequestContentType);
        TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Content-Length: ' + lParam.Size.ToString ); I test it and work  thank you I need now to knew about cookies

Comment: one more question if this site need token like sid for example can i do it by send get method to grab token and send it again or there is an other method to do it Please make example for this site by asking site with sid string and send it again thank you

Comment: Those are new questions that need to be asked separately.

Comment: Thank you I will put it soon thank you verry match :)